# Correctly provide separated streaming feedback from PowerShell 5.1 remote Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

PowerShell is designed to support and favor a streaming output style (where output and user feedback become available as they're generated, instead of being dumped when the script finishes). PowerShell provides the assorted `Write` cmdlets, their streams, and their redirect functionality to enable this style.

However, when using `Invoke-Command`, stream redirection behavior when operating in a remote PSSession varies depending on the stream used.

For example:

```
# Information redirect works as expected when invoking locally
>Invoke-Command { 'output'; Write-Host 'info' } 6>$Null
output

# Information redirect gets ignored when invoking remotely
# (assuming a remote session has already been created as $session)
>Invoke-Command -Session $session { 'output'; Write-Host 'info' } 6>$Null
output
info
```

(`Write-Host` used for simplicity, the same behavior occurs using `Write-Information -InformationAction Continue`)

Experimentation shows stream behavior varies by stream:

- Success (1) and Error (2) output redirect as normal
- Warning (3) and Verbose (4) output unconditionally similar to Information (6), but their formatting is preserved
- Debug (5) redirects as normal (although the continuation prompt doesn't redirect)

I can see a few custom ways to jury-rig streaming output that could subsequently be filtered easily (e.g. outputting to Success with an identifying prefix).

Is there a good way to stream separate output and feedback from a remote command that would adhere to some form of PowerShell common practices, or a way to get the redirection to behave as expected?

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem has been around for quite a while, possibly always; it is discussed in detail in [GitHub issue #9585](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9585). As of PowerShell 7.2, there's no good workaround I'm aware of.

Comment: @mklement0 - I had a feeling this was the case, but I wasn't seeing any relevant SO questions, and the documentation on streams, redirection, and `Invoke-Command` makes no mention of this, so I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something obvious -- or, failing that, provide something resembling documentation.